# Redirection not working with ajax and PHP in a login form. It remains in index page

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

When user fills out the both form fields with email and password and hit sign in button
My script is working fine but after clicking sign in button I want to redirect user to the home page
but user remain in index page and when I type in browser url bar like
localhost/my_site-name/home.php
the system takes me in and I see all session variables which I echo in this page for checking purpose
so I want when the user click sign in button the user automatically redirect to home page here is my code

```
 <form class="form-inline" method="post" action="" id="loginForm">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-5">
        <li class="nav-item">
           <input class="form-control mr-sm-2 input-signUp-form js-signInEmail" type="email" name="signInEmail" placeholder="Email"/>
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2 input-signUp-form js-signInPassword" type="password" name="signInPassword" placeholder="password"/>
           <button  class="btn btn-danger my-2 my-sm-0 js-signInButton" type="submit" name="signInButton">Sign In <i class="fas fa-heart"></i></button>
        </li>
        <p class="ml-2">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1"> Remember Me!
            <span><a href="#" class="ml-4 mt-2">Forget Password</a></span>

        </p>
    </ul>
</form>
```

and here is my script code which i incuded at the bottom of the page after the jquery link adedd

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".js-signInButton").click(function(){
       var signInemail = $(".js-signInEmail").val();
       var signInPassword = $(".js-signInPassword").val();
       $.ajax({
           url:"signIn.php",
           type:"POST",
           data:{
             "signInEmail":signInemail,
             "signInPassword":signInPassword
           },
           success: function (html) {
               if(html == 'true'){
                    // alert("Successfull Login");
                   window.location.href = "home.php";
               }
               else {
                   alert("Error Login");
               }
           }
       });
    });
});
```

and this is my signIn.php file code which used to verify email and password

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include_once ("includes/config.php");
    $signInEmail = $_POST['signInEmail'];
    $signInPassword = $_POST['signInPassword'];
    // for selecting user email and password if it is in database
    $userSignInSql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email ='$signInEmail' AND user_password ='$signInPassword'";
    $userSignInQuery = mysqli_query($conn, $userSignInSql);
    $userSignInRows = mysqli_num_rows($userSignInQuery);
    $userSignInArray = mysqli_fetch_array($userSignInQuery);
    // if we found match then proceed next
    if ($userSignInRows > 0) {
        // in here i update the user online status form 0 to 1
        $sqlUpdate = "UPDATE users SET user_online_status = '1' WHERE user_email='$signInEmail'";
        $updateResult = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlUpdate);
        // in here i perform this query to select user online status after updating it
        $select = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email ='$signInEmail'";
        $selectResult = mysqli_query($conn, $select);
        $updateArray = mysqli_fetch_array($selectResult);
        $_SESSION['onlineStatus'] = $updateArray['user_online_status'];
        $_SESSION['signInId'] = $userSignInArray['user_id'];
        $_SESSION['signInEmail'] = $userSignInArray['user_email'];
        $_SESSION['signInName'] = $userSignInArray['user_full_name'];
        echo "true";
    }
    else {
        echo "error";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Try `if (html.trim() == "true")`. You may be sending extra whitespace before the echo.

Comment: Also, check the Network tab to see what the full response is.

Comment: May be better to do it in the PHP using a `header('Location home.php');`

Comment: @RiggsFolly That doesn't work with AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Try with echo exit;

```
if ($userSignInRows > 0) {

   // in here i update the user online status form 0 to 1
   $sqlUpdate = "UPDATE users SET user_online_status = '1' WHERE user_email='$signInEmail'";
   $updateResult = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlUpdate);

   // in here i perform this query to select user online status after updating it
   $select = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email ='$signInEmail'";
   $selectResult = mysqli_query($conn, $select);
   $updateArray = mysqli_fetch_array($selectResult);

   $_SESSION['onlineStatus'] = $updateArray['user_online_status'];

   $_SESSION['signInId'] = $userSignInArray['user_id'];
   $_SESSION['signInEmail'] = $userSignInArray['user_email'];
   $_SESSION['signInName'] = $userSignInArray['user_full_name'];

   echo "true";
   echo exit;
```

}

or  you can echo 1; echo exit;

in script just check

```
if(html){
                  
  window.location.href = "home.php";


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the success script of Ajax, try like this and see what happens.

```
success: function (html) {
   window.location.href = "home.php";
}
```

if this is redirecting to home page definitely the statement  `if(html == 'true'){` is returning false. If it is not redirecting to home page check you have given the path correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try triple equals, because you get a string not a boolean in response.

```
 success: function (html) {
                   if(html === 'true'){
                        // alert("Successfull Login");
                       window.location.href = "home.php";
                   }
                   else {
                       alert("Error Login");
                   }
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

use e.preventDefault() in your script. This line will not submit your form by php and your script will run properly. Try this!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".js-signInButton").click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var signInemail = $(".js-signInEmail").val();
       var signInPassword = $(".js-signInPassword").val();
       $.ajax({
           url:"signIn.php",
           type:"POST",
           data:{
             "signInEmail":signInemail,
             "signInPassword":signInPassword
           },
           success: function (html) {
               if(html == 'true'){
                    // alert("Successfull Login");
                   window.location.href = "home.php";
               }
               else {
                   alert("Error Login");
               }
           }
       });
    });
});
```